# Angularjs (ng-click , ng-change) directive not working with icheck plugin

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, icheck

I know this has already been asked but am not being able to solve the issue when using icheck plugin.

I have some checkbox as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>
  <input i-check type="checkbox" ng-model="Data.privacy.personal" ng-checked='true' ng-disabled='true' >
  Store & Share Personal Information
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>
  <input data-i-check type="checkbox"  ng-model="Data.privacy.anualreport" ng-checked='true' ng-click="registerprivacy($event)">
  Publish annual report of your job stats
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label><input i-check type="checkbox" ng-model="Data.privacy.share"  ng-change="registerprivacy()" >
        Publish & Share your job postings on Media
    </label>
</div>
```

I've created a directive `icheck` as follows:

```
app.directive('iCheck', function($timeout, $parse) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
            return $timeout(function() {
                var value = $attrs['value'];
                $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue){
                    $(element).iCheck('updated');
                })

                $scope.$watch($attrs['ngDisabled'], function(newValue) {
                    $(element).iCheck(newValue ? 'disable':'enable');
                    $(element).iCheck('updated');
                })

                return $(element).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
                    radioClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
                });
            },300);
        }
    };
});
```

And finally the `registerprivacy` function is as follows in my controller:

```
$scope.registerprivacy = function(){
          alert("test");
          //alert(value);
    };
```

The problem is that the `ng-click` and `ng-change` is not triggering, however if i comment the `icheck` directive the `ng-click` and `ng-change` works **perfectly** .

If the `icheck` directive is not used the checkbox are not rendered and just for info if i use the jquery approach of icheck instead:

```
$(blabla).iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
    });
```

the checkbox are rendered but the `ng-click` and `ng-change` are not triggered.

How to make both the checkbox to be rendred with icheck and the `ng-click` and `ng-change` directives to work?

Comment: im also having problem with ng change or click using icheck, hope someone can help up

Answer (score 4):

Use ng-change instead of ng-click when using icheck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by adding the following block of code at the end of the `icheck.js` file and creating a directive in app.js

## End of icheck.js:

```
$(function () {
    $('input').iCheck();
    $('input.all').on('ifChecked ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        if (event.type == 'ifChecked') {
            $('input.check').iCheck('check');
        } else {
            $('input.check').iCheck('uncheck');
        }
    });
    $('input.check').on('ifUnchecked', function(event) {
        $('input.all').iCheck('uncheck');
    });
});
```

## App directive in app.js:

```
app.directive('icheck', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function($scope, element, $attrs, ngModel) {
        return $timeout(function() {
          var value = $attrs['value'];

          $scope.$watch($attrs['ngModel'], function(newValue){
            $(element).iCheck('update');
          })

          return $(element).iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
          }).on('ifChanged', function(event) {
            if ($(element).attr('type') === 'checkbox' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
              $scope.$apply(function() {
                return ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.checked);
              });
            }
            if ($(element).attr('type') === 'radio' && $attrs['ngModel']) {
              return $scope.$apply(function() {
                return ngModel.$setViewValue(value);
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```